# why my django flatpages cannot show in heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-flatpages

I followed https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/ and 
I created a flatpage using my own template in http://localhost:8000/about-me/ and it works fine. 
But when i've pushed it into heroku and reproduced to create one page, the server returns **Internal Server Error**

the Server log :

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 283, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in **call**
    response = self.get_response(request)

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 153, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 30, in server_error
    t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 157, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html

Comment: You need to find your server log and post the stack trace, we can't guess what's wrong.

Comment: also i cannot use redirects app on heroku.. why~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace tells me that it can't find your `500.html` template. Maybe if you give it one ti will clear up the error message to what the actual problem is.

Is the domain correct for the Site ID used by your flatpage? For instance if locally you say you site is the "localhost", but in heroku if it's served by "dev.internalnet.example" domain, that could cause issues.

Also, try setting DEBUG=True in settings.py, hit the page and you should get a fancy page with the exact stack trace causing the issue (and then it won't need to look for a `500.html` template, although you should have one).

Comment: Yes i have turned debug on now, and it gots django 404 page 'No FlatPage matches the given query.'
but i did add the page and set the site with new domain

Comment: i have 500.html and 404.html in my templates dir already.

also i notice that the Redirects app doesn't works either on heroku

Comment: OK i found my Site ID = 1 in my settings.py but the SITE_ID which is matched my flatpage is 2 in heroku database.